# Dropbox API - Dropbox ruby gem (Tim Morgan): How to authorize

Tags: ruby, api, authorization, dropbox

I want to write a ruby app for personal use that access my personal dropbox through their API.
I'm using Tim Morgan gem 'dropbox' version 1.1.1
What I don't understand is the difference between a developer_key and a consumer_key. The gem docs say that I have to use the consumer_key, but when I registered my app on dropbox.com I received only a developer key secret pair (and that's what I put in Dropbox::Session.new)

Anyway the error I get from ruby at every API call is:

```
Dropbox::UnsuccessfulResponseError: HTTP status Net::HTTPBadRequest
```

any idea??

Answer (score 3):

You have to redirect your user to the oauth page where he will grant you the authorization to access the datas. This can be done wit something like that:

```
  dropbox_session = Dropbox::Session.new('bla', 'blabla')
  redirect_to dropbox_session.authorize_url(:oauth_callback => root_url)
```